# Generate an Excel file Using Python Xlsxwriter on a Windows Server 2016

Tags: python, windows, server, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to generate an Excel file using Python 2.7 and xlsxwriter on a server running Windows Server 2016?  Is having Excel on the box a dependency for generating the file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no, python can read/write python files using various packages without needing excel.

Comment: Look up the Python Excel I/O packages.  They should answer this question an the ones that follow.

Comment: No, you can do without Excel.